# What to do about unicode?

Tags: python, xml, unicode

I have the following code stripping white lines from xml files:

```
#working for all files in dir.
from pathlib import Path


for path in Path(r'attachments\75090058\Status\XMLsend').glob('*.xml'):
    with open(path, 'r+') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        f.seek(0, 0)
        for line in lines:
            if line.strip() != '':
                f.write(line)
        f.truncate()
```

It was working very well, however now I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 1291: character maps to <undefined>
```

What to do?

Please help!

Comment: Please [edit] to clarify the title and show the full traceback where the error occurs. Is the problem character in a file name or in its contents? Why do you conclude this has anythoing with Unicode to do? (It probably does, but nothing here shows us how.)

Comment: Sorry @tripleee I have limited knowledge knowledge on UniCode

Comment: Perhaps see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try encoding the text into a `UTF-8 format`.

Try this code out:

```
from pathlib import Path

for path in Path(r'attachments\75090058\Status\XMLsend').glob('*.xml'):
    with open(path, 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        f.seek(0, 0)
        for line in lines:
            if line.strip() != '':
                f.write(line)
        f.truncate()
```